# What amp breaker for 4500w electrical oven and 9600w induction cooktop on same circuit

Tags: electrical, circuit-breaker, stove, range

What amp breaker should I use for a 4500 watt electrical oven and 9600 watt induction cooktop?

Currently, I have a 6 gauge wire and a 50 Amp breaker, and my current electrical range is hooked up to this.

I want to replace my current range with induction cooktop and electric oven.

Do I need to update my 50 Amp breaker to be a 60 Amp breaker?
I saw some calculation and this table - http://www.naffainc.com/x/CB2/Elect/EHtmFiles/Table%20220-19.htm

**BUT my cooktop is more than 8.75 KW so I wonder if I can't connect both on the same electric circuit?**

If helpful, the model and electrical specifications for the two appliances are listed below:

**Stove** - POWER

Rated Current20 A

Max Power Consumption - 4.5 kW

Amperage Rating At 240 - 20 volts

Voltage 208 - 240 V

**Induction** Electrical Specification

Element Wattage - 5400

Wattage - 9600 watts

Amperage - 40 amperes

Voltage - 240 volts

https://www.bestbuy.com/site/bosch-800-series-36-built-in-electric-induction-cooktop-with-5-elements-and-homeconnect-frameless/6335119.p?skuId=6335119

https://www.cnet.com/products/samsung-nv51t5511ss-oven-built-in-stainless-steel/

Comment: Why are you trying to combine breakers?

Comment: @Matt -- they are replacing a range with separates -- combining cooktop + oven on the same circuit is *expressly* permitted by NEC 220.55

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Table 220.55 and combining appliances

Since you're replacing a range with a cooktop+oven as separates, we start with NEC Table 220.55 Note 4:

> 4. Branch-Circuit Load. It shall be permissible to calculate the branch-circuit load for one range in accordance with Table 220.55. The branch-circuit
>    load for one wall-mounted oven or one counter-mounted cooking unit shall be the nameplate rating of the appliance. The branch-circuit load for a
>    counter-mounted cooking unit and not more than two wall-mounted ovens, all supplied from a single branch circuit and located in the same room,
>    shall be calculated by adding the nameplate rating of the individual appliances and treating this total as equivalent to one range.

As a result, we can treat your new setup as equivalent to a 14.1kW range.  We then use the Note 1 rule for ranges over 12kW:

> 1. Over 12 kW through 27 kW ranges all of same rating. For ranges individually rated more than 12 kW but not more than 27 kW, the maximum
>    demand in Column C shall be increased 5 percent for each additional kilowatt of rating or major fraction thereof by which the rating of individual
>    ranges exceeds 12 kW.

Given that a single 12kW range is treated as an 8kW load (first entry in Column C of the table), we have at most a 15% bump over that 8kW, or 9.2kW of load from your new appliances.  This is no sweat whatsoever for a 50A circuit on 6AWG wire, as it comes out to just over 38A at 240VAC.

Comment: This is such a "you" question :)

Comment: Thanks for the answer @ThreePhaseEel.
One thing that I did not understand, is why we go to note 1 and not note 2 as the cooktop and the stove has different ratings?

"Over 83/4 kW through 27 kW ranges of unequal ratings"

Comment: @Yuvi -- we thank people around here by upvoting and accepting their answers :)

Comment: Also, I am not sure I understand where "Given that a single 12kW range is treated as an 8kW load" came from. From what I can see in the table, it is written "Column C,
Maximum Demand (kW) (See Notes) (Not over 12 kW Rating)" and mine is over 12kW. What am I missing?

Comment: @Yuvi -- the Note 1 procedure (quoted in the answer) starts with that number from the first row of Column C and adds on to it

Comment: And what is "not over 12 kW rating" referring too in Column C header?

Comment: @Yuvi -- the nameplate rating of the range load, or in your case, the sum of the nameplate ratings of your appliances since you have separate appliances sharing a branch circuit

Comment: So in that case, the sum is more than 12kW but the header says "Not over 12 kW Rating". I am missing something?

Comment: @Yuvi -- what you're missing is that the Note 1 procedure says to add to the value from Column C :)